# Split string by position not character

Tags: python, regex, split

We know that `anchors`, `word boundaries`, and `lookaround` match at a position, rather than matching a character.
Is it possible to split a string by one of the preceding ways with regex (specifically in python)?

For example consider the following string:

```
"ThisisAtestForchEck,Match IngwithPosition."
```

So i want the following result (the sub-strings that start with uppercase letter but not precede by space ):

```
['Thisis', 'Atest', 'Forch' ,'Eck,' ,'Match Ingwith' ,'Position.']
```

If i split with grouping i get:

```
>>> re.split(r'([A-Z])',s)
['', 'T', 'hisis', 'A', 'test', 'F', 'orch', 'E', 'ck,', 'M', 'atchingwith', 'P', 'osition.']
```

And this is the result with look-around :

```
>>> re.split(r'(?<=[A-Z])',s)
['ThisisAtestForchEck,MatchingwithPosition.']
>>> re.split(r'((?<=[A-Z]))',s)
['ThisisAtestForchEck,MatchingwithPosition.']
>>> re.split(r'((?<=[A-Z])?)',s)
['ThisisAtestForchEck,MatchingwithPosition.']
```

Note that if i want to split by sub-strings that start with uppercase and are  preceded by a space, e.g.:

```
['Thisis', 'Atest', 'Forch' ,'Eck,' ,'Match ', Ingwith' ,'Position.']
```

I can use `re.findall`, viz.:

```
>>> re.findall(r'([A-Z][^A-Z]*)',s)
['Thisis', 'Atest', 'Forch', 'Eck,', 'Match ', 'Ingwith', 'Position.']
```

But what about the first example: is it possible to solve it with `re.findall`?

Comment: You can't do it with `split` because that uses the regexp to define the delimiters, which are considered separate from the elements being split. What's wrong with using `re.findall` as in your last example?

Comment: @Barmar Yeah,i know but as i say in question can i split the first example with `re.finall`? i think `split` is more flexible for such tasks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A way with `re.findall`:

```
re.findall(r'(?:[A-Z]|^[^A-Z\s])[^A-Z\s]*(?:\s+[A-Z][^A-Z]*)*',s)
```

When you decide to change your approach from `split` to `findall`, the first job consists to reformulate your requirements: "I want to split the string on each uppercase letter non preceded by a space" => "I want to find one or more substrings separed by space that begins with an uppercase letter except from the start of the string *(if the string doesn't start with an uppercase letter)*"

Comment: This is good and tricky way! can you do it with `look-around`?

Answer (score 2):

```
 (?<!\s)(?=[A-Z])
```

You can use this to split with regex module as re does not support split at 0 width assertions.

```
import regex
x="ThisisAtestForchEck,Match IngwithPosition."
print regex.split(r"(?<![\s])(?=[A-Z])",x,flags=regex.VERSION1)
```

or

```
print [i for i in regex.split(r"(?<![\s])(?=[A-Z])",x,flags=regex.VERSION1) if i]
```

See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/sJ9gM7/65

Comment: @Kasra eh!!!!!! you can do `pip install regex` .it is a python module.Just that it does not come by itself

Comment: Yeah, and as i say this is a good answer, but i have to wait more ;) if i don't get an answer i'll accept your answer! for now plus 1!

Answer (score 1):

I know this might be less convenient because of the tuple nature of the result. But I think that this `findall` finds what you need:

```
re.findall(r'((?<!\s)[A-Z]([^A-Z]|(?<=\s)[A-Z])*)', s)
## returns [('Thisis', 's'), ('Atest', 't'), ('Forch', 'h'), ('Eck,', ','), ('Match Ingwith', 'h'), ('Position.', '.')]
```

This can be used in the following list comprehension to give the desired output:

```
[val[0] for val in re.findall(r'((?<!\s)[A-Z]([^A-Z]|(?<=\s)[A-Z])*)', s)]
## returns ['Thisis', 'Atest', 'Forch', 'Eck,', 'Match Ingwith', 'Position.']
```

And here is a hack that uses `split`:

```
re.split(r'((?<!\s)[A-Z]([^A-Z]|(?<=\s)[A-Z])*)', s)[1::3]
## returns ['Thisis', 'Atest', 'Forch', 'Eck,', 'Match Ingwith', 'Position.']
```

Comment: @Kasra ... hi, let me know if there is something wrong with this answer, I'd love to learn

Comment: Its not wrong its a good answer thanks! but i dont want to use `slicing`!

Comment: @Kasra ok. in case you are interested, I've just edited my answer to return the desired list from `findall` using a list comprehension.

Answer (score 0):

try capture using this pattern

```
([A-Z][a-z]*(?: [A-Z][a-z]*)*)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/yW4aZ3/247)